# Using MySQL workbench to migrate from local to RDS

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using the MySQL workbench to migrate from my local database to an amazon RDS instance. I have several tables and some views. The tables copy over fine, however the views appear to fail. It seems as though non-capitalised lettering is used in the names on the views for example:

`Error: Table 'scraperv3.userchoice' doesn't exist.`

But a table `UserChoice` does. I have tried using capital letters for these, and the view is created although without any data, making it appear to not actually link to the tables it references. Is there a solution to this?